# Why is my ng-style not working?

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I am trying to set a style with `ng-style`.  I have an array:

```
scope.order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And I am trying to use it to set the order on a `div`:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-show="country.usesAddrDistrict" ng-style="{'order': order.indexOf(3)}">
 ...
</div>
```

And the order is not being set.

I have tried `ng-style="{order: order.indexOf(3)}"`
  And that doesn't work either.  I am using Angular 1.5.8.  How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

your code looks fine, you only need to make the array visible on your template, instead of using a block scope declaration.

try to define your array attached to the $scope.

```
$scope.order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

or if you using controller as syntax

```
this.order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It is attached to `scope`.  I missed that when copying over to SO.

Comment: i've made a plnkr with your div. the compiled html has the style {order: 3} applied correctly. https://plnkr.co/edit/ZPty3Fp2cKvkSTgSPyyE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the order to $scope.

```js
let order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller("example", ["$scope", function (s) {
          s.order = order;
      }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="example">
    <div ng-style="{'order': order.indexOf(3)}"> Order:  {{order.indexOf(3)}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is attached to `scope`.  I missed that when copying over to SO.  I can get the `index.orderOf(3)` to log to the page, but it isn't applying to the `style`.

Comment: It is apply to style tag. can you please inspect element and check?